# Can I restore a lost Firefox add-on the name of which I've forgotten?

Tags: firefox, search, icons, browser-addons

I upgraded my Firefox from 30 to 39 and one of my add-ons disappeared.  I don't see it in Customize, and I can't figure out which of my add-ons it is or remember the name of it (I know, I have too many add-ons).

Is there a way to quickly scan all the add-on icons?

It was a red cross.  If you click on it once, it restores the most recently closed tab.  If you click on it again, the second most recently closed tab, and so on.  If you click on the little down-arrow, it shows you a list of your recent tabs.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer: **Ctrl+T** opens a new tab; **Ctrl+Shift+T** restores the last closed tab (and can do so repeatedly); **Alt+S** brings up the History menu, from which you can view recently closed tabs. So is this addon necessary?

Comment: Could this be the _undo closed tabs_ addon? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/undo-closed-tabs-button/

Comment: If I can't find my original one, with the red plus in the icon, I will try yours, @Adam.

Comment: For Windows, you can use: [**MozBackup**](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) to backup extensions, cookies, bookmarks, etc. Then when something changes they are easy to restore.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, sort of by accident.  I still don't completely understand what happened....  I noticed that the icon for my add-on "Session Manager" was missing.  I was having trouble restoring it, until I uninstalled and deleted the add-on, and then re-installed and activated it.

After that, not only did the Session Manager icon reappear, so did the red plus, which apparently is called "Undo Close."  And get this -- it is apparently not related to any add-on, but is part of the basic Firefox browser itself.

I am certain the icon was not available to add to the toolbar (in customize) until I did the re-install of the Session Manager.

Both Session Manager and Undo Close are working fine now.

Very mysterious.

---

Edit - 7/25

I noticed that some other add-ons weren't working properly.  I was able adjust a setting on one and get it to work, but another, which didn't have any settings, didn't want to work no matter what I did.

I found https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/982460 which solved my problem.  I had to delete three files in my profile: extensions.ini, compatibility.ini, and extensions.sqlite.  Then I had to delete the add-on, close firefox, and re-install the add-on.

Apparently my extension files were corrupt.